# ASP.NET MVC Filtering results by date returns 0 results

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime

I am trying to filter the results of a database query by date. The user will input a date value as a string and then I use that string to compare to the date of every query result to try to find a match, however there is never a match, even when I know one exists.

Query and filtering:

```
var documents = from s in db.Documents
                            select s;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    documents = documents.Where(s => s.Order_Date.ToString().Contains(searchString) || 
                                     s.Comment.Contains(searchString));
}
```

It should be noted that if the `searchString` is found in the `Comment` column, then it works fine. But again, there is never a match for date.

In the SQL table that the app connects to the column `Order_Date` is of `date` datatype (not `datetime`). However in the model `Order_Date` is a `DateTime` variable because as far as I'm aware C# does not have just date.

Here is an example of the problem:

[image: example]

**Result**

[image: result]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to keep the values 'date-like' instead of using strings. `DateTime.Parse` your user input. Create 2 `var`s: `dateFrom` and `dateTo`. Set `dateFrom` as '0:0:0' of the input and `dateTo` as '23:59:59' of the input, and search for `s.order_date >= dateFrom && s.order_date <= dateTo`

Comment: I don't understand the second part of what you're saying. The comparison ````s.order_date >= dateFrom && s.order_date <= dateTo```` does not use the searchString at all?

Comment: `dateFrom` and `dateTo` would be midnight of the date and 11:59:59pm (23:59:59) of the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing `11/8/2004` with `s.Order_Date.ToString()`. This approach has several problems:

- Maybe `s.Order_Date` contains `2004-08-11` but when you do `s.Order_Date.ToString()` it turns to month-day-year date format `8/11/2004` (instead day-month-year) and `8/11/2004 != 11/8/2004`
- What happens if user enters `11/08/2004` ? `11/08/2004 != 11/8/2004`. User will don't understand why they are no results.

If you want to search by date the best solution is to use a date entry control. If for your UX is important to enter date in a text control instead a  date control then you should to tokenize text and try to identify dates on text, convert to date and use a date to compare on linq expression.

```cs
DateTime? search_date_start = tokenize_and_extract_date_start(searchString)
DateTime? search_date_end = tokenize_and_extract_date_end(searchString)
String? search_comment = remove_dates_from_search_string(searchString)

documents = 
    documents
    .Where(s => 
       search_date_start == null || 
       s.Order_Date >= search_date_start) 
    )
    .Where(s => 
       search_date_end == null || 
       s.Order_Date <= search_date_end) 
    )
    .Where(s => 
       search_comment == null ||
       s.Comment.Contains(search_comment)
    );
```

Comment: This is good information but seems way over complicated compared to the method I found to do it based on Jonathan's comment, but thank you for typing this out. I'm going to mark this as the correct answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using Jonathan's comment. This is the simplest way to do it:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    try
    {
        var test = DateTime.Parse(searchString);
        documents = documents.Where(s => s.Order_Date == test);
    }
    catch (FormatException e)
    {
        documents = documents.Where(s => s.Comment.Contains(searchString));
    }
}
```